# Создание и поддержка нескольких ViewController

Tags: objective-c, mvc

Возник вопрос по созданию и поддержке нескольких ViewController. У меня есть модель, в которой я оперирую данными. Есть ViewController. Я хочу создать несколько ViewController для более легкой навигации по коду и масштабируемости проекта.

В классе ViewController в методе viewDidLoad
я вызываю, то есть создаю, экземпляр класса Model:

```
model=[[Model alloc]init];
```

В случае если у меня будет несколько ViewController, в каждом мне нужно будет импортировать библиотеку модели, и чтобы получить доступ к её переменным и методам, мне нужно будет создавать новый экземпляр. Или в objective c, при выделении памяти под объект он становится доступен по всему проекту, и невозможно создать несколько экземпляров одного и того же класса?

Что конкретно я упускаю/ошибаюсь и как это можно реализовать?
Занимаюсь objective c всего месяц, до этого писал на c#, там несколько все иначе было.
Заранее благодарю за любой ответ.

Comment: Наследование?))

Answer (score 1):

`model=[[Model alloc]init];` каждый раз возвращает новый объект класса Model, в obj-c нет ограничения на количество экземпляров одного и того же класса если не считать singleton-ов, но они как и в c++ делаются с помощью статической переменной. Вообще большинство переменных в obj-c это умные указатели у которых при помощи ARC контролируется количество ссылок (не в рантайме, а при сборке). Естественно, я говорю не про простые типы и не про то что человек сам может наваять в obj-c с нуля забив на типы от apple